# How to rewrite query string to slashes in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

This is my url: http://dev.minestatus.co/profile.php?id=2. I am using laravel 5.4. I want my application be backward compatible with old links.

I've been trying to write it like this, http://dev.minestatus.co/profile/2

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=(.*)$  
RewriteRule ^.*$ /profile/%
```

This is what I have come up with so far, as you see there is still "?id=" which I don't want.
http://dev.minestatus.co/profile/2?id=2

Comment: `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \h/profile\.php\?id=(\d*)` \n `RewriteRule ^ /profile/%1? [R=303,L]` (the 303 is for testing)

Comment: @Deadooshka it redirected, but the url was http://dev.minestatus.co/profile/2?id=2

Comment: `?` added to the replacement end. Also consider the [`QSD`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsd) flag

Comment: What is the URL you are linking to in your application? Which version of Apache are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably what you are looking for:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=(\d+)$  
RewriteRule ^/?profile\.php$ /profile/%1 [R=301,QSD]
```

This will externally redirect an incoming request to the resource `/profile.php?id=2` to the URL `/profile/2`, so change the URL in the browser.

---

In case you receive a http status 500 (internal server error) for this chances are that your http server is a very old version and you have to use a workaround to get a more or less clean result:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=(\d+)$  
RewriteRule ^/?profile\.php$ /profile/%1? [R=301]
```

The above rule set should work likewise in the http servers (virtual) host configuration or in dynamic configuration files ("`.htaccess`" style files). A dynamic configuration file would have to be placed inside the http server hosts `DOCUMENT_ROOT` location.

---

And a general hint: you should always prefer to place such rules inside the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those files are notoriously error prone, hard to debug and they really slow down the server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have control over the host configuration (read: really cheap hosting service providers) or if you have an application that relies on writing its own rewrite rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: You have this backwards, maybe I'm confused, this will rewrite profile.php?id=2 to profile/2? It isn't working in laravel

Comment: @DarkMoria This depends on what you actually mean by the term "to rewrite a URL". It is ambiguous which is why I try not to use it directly. Some people use it (correctly in my eyes) to describe the technical process of rewriting an incoming request to some internal resource. Others use it in some strange "virtual" meaning trying to express that they want to publish a resource under a different URL. Both interpretations express more or less the exact opposite which is why the term is ambiguous.

Comment: @DarkMoria So I suggest you make your actual question more precise: what is the URL actually requested and what is the actual internal resource that should be called.

Comment: @DarkMoria Oh, and... "It isn't working" has _never_ helped anyone anywhere at any time to solve an issue ;-) _Be precise!_ What do you actually mean by that _exactly_?

Comment: To clarify on your comment @arkascha, the regex does not match the incoming request, as a result, one might say, it simply does not work.

Comment: @DarkMoria Hm, interesting. May I ask how you decide that the expression does not match? An incoming request to `/profile/2` (taken from your updated question) will definitely be matched by the expression in my answer. Since you do not in any form react on my first comment here and explain what it actually is you want to do there currently is nothing more I can say.

Comment: The incoming request is profile.php?id=2, if that is what it means to type it in the url bar and press enter. You are requesting the file profile.php with get param id=2. I just want an expression that would rewrite it /profile/2 so my index.php can load the views.

Comment: @DarkMoria Ah! Ok! That is something _totally_ different! And you are sure your setup does the reverse rewriting which is required to be able to serve this request then?

Comment: I'm not so sure on the reverse rewriting, and the reasoning for it. I had a custom php framework in which I built my network of sites on. Overtime a few of my sites acquired several hundred back links added up, which did affect my seo ranking. When I upgraded to Laravel, I was more productive in creating, but I lost the ability to support the .php extension in the url with get parameters, and my new links are now model, view, controller, styled. Thank you for your help though,  @Deadooshka solved this riddle for me.

Comment: @DarkMoria That is more or less the solution I now posted in my answer, the version for old apache http servers. Glad you solved your issue, though!

Comment: @DarkMoria And a note: The URL style you now use has nothing to do with MVC, that can also be done with the "traditional", parameter based URL style. Your currently style is typically referred to as "SEO friendly", since many bots ignore traditional GET arguments (which _does_ make sense).

Comment: for some reason, his rewrite method works, and I am sent to the right page /profile/2, when I try yours, it just goes to the default laravel error page, NotFoundHttpException, which is normal is this case. The url does not change.

Comment: "bots ignore traditional GET arguments" - Bit of an aside, but bots don't ignore GET args. These (non-URL param) URLs are known as "user-friendly", they have nothing to do with SEO directly (they help click-through rates as _users_ find them more friendly).

Answer (score 0):

Use below rule,

```
RewriteEngine On
Rewritecond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
Rewritecond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\d]+)$ $1.php?id=$2 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this rule in your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^profile/([^/]*)$ /profile.php?id=$1 [L]
```

It will leave you with the URL: `http://dev.minestatus.co/profile/2`. Make sure you clear your cache before testing this.